# Uncheck "Formatting" in MSWord tracked changes Markup Options? (Office 365 for Mac v16.26)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to use an AutoOpen() sub for all docs to (1) turn on tracked changes [this part is successful] and (2) stop Word from displaying formatting changes in the sidebar.  Word defaults to displaying all comments and formatting in balloons, which is what I want, but I don't actually need to track or review formatting changes.

See ![screenshot]https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIl3F.jpg for a screenshot of what I want to accomplish automatically via Macro.  When I choose Record Macro, uncheck Formatting, and stop recording, no code has been generated in VBE. There doesn't seem to be an available property in VBA for Word (Mac or otherwise) that will accomplish this goal.

Here's my current AutoOpen() code:

```
Sub AutoOpen()

    ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = True

    With ActiveDocument
        .TrackFormatting = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Turning off tracking formatting, as I'm currently doing, only works going forward, so all existing changes will still be displayed until I uncheck the Formatting option. It's a partial solution, at least.

I'm also aware there is a property to show/hide revisions as a whole (i.e. I could include the code: .ShowRevisions = False), but that's not quite what I'm looking for here, since I only want to hide the formatting (I would expect it to be something like .ShowFormatting, but that is not a property in VBA).

Any thoughts/suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those settings are in a different part of the object model, under the `View` object. Here's a code snippet that shows how to turn off the *display* of tracked changes. Note that this *doesn't remove them* from the document, it only supresses the display. In order to remove these revisions from the document it would be necessary to accept or reject the changes.

```
Dim doc As Word.Document

Set doc = ActiveDocument
doc.TrackRevisions = True
doc.TrackFormatting = False
doc.ActiveWindow.View.ShowFormatChanges = False
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for - thank you!